# Navigation Bar Bootstrap Low Resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I am currently working on a nvaigation bar for a website which will mostly be used on mobile. Here is a link to the codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQjWXW

Markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-images"></i> Page</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
                &#9776;
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row justify-content-between ml-auto">
                <li class="dropdown order-1">

                    <button type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">Login <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mt-1">
                      <li class="p-3">
                            <form id="login-form" class="form" role="form" action="index.php">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon group-span"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <input id="username" placeholder="Nutzername" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Bitte geben Sie einen Nutzernamen an.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon group-span"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Passwort" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Bitte geben Sie ein Passwort an.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                                </div>
                                <div id="login-message" class="small "></div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

On lower resolution I get this kind of screwed behaviour: 
[image]

Instead I want it to be like this:
[image]

Can someone please show me where I messed up?